# Why is the answer "most of them" instead of "most of whom"?

Tags: pronouns

In this sentence:

> During the American Revolutionary War, about 14000 British
>   loyalists returned to Britain, _____ in 1783.
>
> A. most of whom.
>   B. most of them.

I know the answer is B, but I can't understand why it's B, what is the diference between them. Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use "whom" this way because a verb is missing.

If it was phrased this way:

> "During the American Revolutionary War, about 14000 British loyalists returned to Britain, most of whom **returned** in 1783."

That would be okay. It is grammatically correct but a little wasteful using the word "returned" twice. That is why your second example using "them" is better, because the word is referring back to the returning British loyalists you have already named.

Comment: +1 Quite correct, although *why* we can't use *most of whom* when there's no verb there is a mystery to me.

Comment: @Araucaria You got me with the million of examples. Lesson learnt

Comment: @RubioRic I like your posts a lot. We've got to make sure our stuff's accurate though (more easily said than done!)  :-)

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks! I agree with you about the accuracy. There is no equivalent "object of a preposition" that I know of in Spanish, my native language. This got me a bit confused. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since Araucaria has demurred, let me venture an explanation for why we cannot say there **most of whom in 1783** but we can say there **most of them in 1783**.  It is Friday "Happy Hour" here so *caveat lector*.

**who** can be a relative pronoun

> About 14,000 people *who were British loyalists* returned to England
>   in 1783.

It heads the relative clause there.

When we wish to use **who** as a relative pronoun but in a way that refers to some portion of the group to which **who** refers, we use the preposition **of**, and when **who** is the object of a preposition its objective case, **whom**, is used.

> About 14,000 people *most of whom* were British loyalists returned
>   to England in 1783.
>
> About 14,000 people, *of whom most* were British loyalists, returned
>   to England in 1783.

Of those who returned, a few just wanted to say hi to their folks. They were not 100% loyalists.

Now **they** is not a relative pronoun. If **they** (nominative case) heads a clause, **they** is a subject, and that clause is not a relative clause.

> About 14,00 people returned to England in 1783.  **They** were loyalists.

And when **they** is the object of a preposition, it too goes into the objective case, **them**.

> About 14,000 people returned to England in 1783. Most **of them** were loyalists.

We can restate that last sentence with ellipsis or omission of the verb **BE**:

> About 14,000 people returned to England in 1783, most of them Ø loyalists.

There is probably a fancy term for **most of them loyalists**,  or there may even be dueling fancy terms, but it comes down to understanding the implicit presence of some form of the verb-to-be there:

> .... most of them [BEING] loyalists.

P.S. And when BE is missing in such a clause, the clause just gloms onto the preceding main clause without any sort of connector.

P.P.S. And it can glom onto the front of the sentence:

> Most of them loyalists, 14,000 people returned to England in 1783.

Comment: Is that supposed to be [*glom on to*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/glom) or [*glom onto*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/glom)? I'm not sure why the same publisher put it two different ways (the examples there use only *on to*). (In COCA the results are skewed slightly towards *onto*.)

Comment: @user2684291: Those are simply vagaries of orthography, which is an imperfect representation of the spoken language.